# How to reattach the "head" of a ground wire?

Tags: repair, wire, ground

I just bought a new turntable and receiver

When I began using it, I noticed there was a loud buzzing sound coming from it.

Looking at the turntable's cables, there are the two Left and Right RCA cables as well as another cable with a missing head (not sure what the proper word is).

I realized this must be the ground cable and it just has uninsulated wire coming out of it.

Can I buy a new ground "head" and reattach it? How do I do this? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a photo of where that cable connected to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A crimp on eyelet or forked spade connector should do. There's nothing particular about a turntable ground wire like there might be for an antenna wire. I'd probably cut off the damaged end, re-strip with the appropriate size tool, and crimp to fresh wire. A locking pliers (Vice-Grip) works will in a pinch. So to speak.

[image]

It's also possible that the wire never had a connector. Some grounding lugs are designed to take a bare wire. Simply wrap the wire once around the lug, under any washer that's present, and snug it down lightly.

Comment: Thank you very much. When I reattach it, where do I connect the ground to? Is it okay to connect it to metal on the receiver, or does it have to be metal found elsewhere?

Comment: The receiver probably has a ground knob somewhere, probably close to any AM antenna connection. You can clamp it under there.

Comment: @Sam: the turntable ground wire *must* go to the receiver. You want the receiver and turntable to have the same ground. Any amp that is designed for a turntable will have a ground (might be marked GND or a [ground symbol](http://i52.tinypic.com/14o7gc5.png)). If it doesn't have one then you could try a random screw on the chassis.

Comment: I just found the ground knob, thanks very much for your help guys. :)